# Fresh ASP.NET Core 2.1 App Engine Project returns 503 Error

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-web-api

I just installed Cloud Tools for Visual Studio, and created a new default ASP.NET Core 2.1 product targeting Google App Engine, using the cloud tools.

When running the fresh default application locally, the default controller returns the sample values. But when deploying to App Engine, the web service returns a 503 error.

`https://my-project-nam.appspot.com/api/values`

`503. That’s an error.`
`The service you requested is not available at this time.`
`Service error -27. That’s all we know.`

Did I miss a step? How can the API values be access on the App Engine production site?

Comment: 503 is usually a temporal error, is it still happening?

Comment: You are right. I restarted the App Engine version, and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), 503 Service Unavailable error means that:
The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.

The error message is quite explicit too: `The service you requested is not available at this time`.

If you get that error again, I suggest you to wait for 5-10min and retry. If the error persists, please contact support.